# JSON.parse returning syntax error only when deployed on pythonanywhere

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, django

I'm new to javascript and web development in general.So this is an app to retrieve and display the last 10 tweets of a Twitter user.It uses AJAX to retrieve the tweets from the Django-powered server.The app works fine on my local machine but when i deploy it on pythonanywhere, the JavaScript part shows a Syntax error.
Following is the script part in the HTML file.

```html
<script>
  $("#HandleForm").on("submit", function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var handle = $('#handle').val();
     get_tweets(handle);
  });

  function get_tweets(handle){
    $.ajax({
        url : "ajax/returntweets/",
        type : "GET",
        data : {handle_data : handle},
        success : function(json){
          var response = $.parseJSON(json)['tweet_data']
          $('#tweet_table').append('<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Tweets of @' + handle + '</li>');

          for(i=0;i<response.length;i++){
            $('#tweet_table').append('<li class="list-group-item">'+response[i]+'</li>');
          }
          $('#tweet_table').append('<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">Tweets End Here!</li>');

        },
    });
  }
</script>
```

This is the views.py returning the tweet data:

```
auth = OAuth1(APIKey, APISecret, AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret)
username = request.GET.get('handle_data')
verificationUrl = ' https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=%s' %username
response = requests.get(verificationUrl, auth=auth)
tweets = []

if response.status_code == 200:
    requestUrl = ' https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?tweet_mode=extended&screen_name=%s&count=10' %username
    r = requests.get(requestUrl, auth=auth,)
    for tweet in r.json():
        tweets.append(tweet['full_text'])
else:
    tweets.append("Invalid Handle")

response_data = {"tweet_data" : tweets}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data))
```

The browser console shows the following error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

`console.log(json)` prints the whole HTML document.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on https://plnkr.co/. or can you attach a screenshot of the error?

Comment: The problem has been fixed.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `JSON.parse` instead `$.parseJSON`  like below code

```
json_string = "{\"name\": \"google\"}"
json_data = JSON.parse(json_string);
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed it for now!Thanks!